# CiviCRM With Drupal, WordPress or Joomla

Tags: joomla, drupal-7, wordpress, civicrm

I am currently working on a collage project where they have following requirement.

Users :

Super admin, Department Head(who will be admin for staff/student of particular department), Staff(who can have access to all the students info of their department),Students(department wise and year wise)

->Awards section(should be seen in their respective profile page)

->Announcements from Department heads to either staff or students or both

->Event calendar

->inter department message exchange by department head and staff

->Department and Staff should have access to all the registered students according to thier year and department wise

->Students can have access to their respective batch information

->blog section where post need to be moderated by their department heads

I am confused if CiviCRM fits into the requirements and if yes which module should i use drupal, joomla or wordpress.

I am good at WordPress and have far more knowledge then i have regarding drupal or joomla. But as of posts of others drupal have better flexibility.

So kindly if any solution which can improve my output.

Thanks and Regards,
LoTR

Comment: They can all provide a solution. For drupal look into Domain access module or Spaces

Comment: Domain access module let me create multiple sites/database. i am not looking for multisite. I want only one site where there is hierarchy of users with full rights to staff and HOD while limited view right to students

Comment: Core permissions will do then. Domain access can also work with subdomains or sub-urls.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a significant piece of work, I don't think you'll get a clear answer here (only opinions). If by "good at wordpress" you mean you are capable of writing WP plugins, you should probably stick to what you know. If you aren't a programmer, more of the requirements may be found in existing Drupal modules, but assembling them well will be a challenge :D

Answer (score 1):

Frankly it looks like you might not need CiviCRM or any CRM at all. But it really depends on what you mean by "Department and Staff should have access to all the registered students according to thier year and department wise." If you mean access to significant amounts of info about those students, info that might be stored in a profile, you might put that into CiviCRM as custom fields. But you could also build profiles in Wordpress though you might need to know PHP.

All the rest of your requirements seem like they can be built in the CMS, maybe with an event module thrown on.

CiviCRM is somewhat better supported under Drupal, but if you know Wordpress better that will like make up the difference.

A project like this needs a complex, comprehensive planning stage to evaluate the needed features and what code base would best support them.